# How do I set the variable if a get value is 0 in php for mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am passing variables in a url to a new php page and want to set an array if the variable value = 0.

The code used to pass the variable is:

```
?type=2
```

My get statement looks like this:

```
$type = intval($_REQUEST['type']);

if ($type = 0)
$itype = array(2,3);
else
$itype = $type;
```

I am then trying to use {$itype} in my SQL query like this:

> AND cid IN ({$itype})

The result I need is when the value is 0  like:

```
?type=0
```

the query to be:

```
AND cid IN (2,3)
```

and if the value is 2 like:

```
?type=2
```

the query to be:

```
AND cid IN (2)
```

This is my solution but I am not sure my methodology is sound. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you should change this line :

```
if ($type = 0) // this assigns 0 to $type
```

to this line

```
if ($type == 0) // this checks if $type == 0
```

then, you can change your sql query like this:

```
$sql_query = "bla bla AND cid IN " . ($type==0 ? "(2,3)" : "(2)") ." bla bla";
```

Comment: I changed the if statement to this:

if ($type == 0)
$itype = '2,3');
else
$itype = $type;

And the query to this:

AND cid IN ($itype)


And now it works. Thank you.